# No se ejecuta crontab desde docker container

Tags: docker, cron, crontab

Estoy tratando de configurar un crontab desde docker, el código que tengo es así:

```
 # Web container
FROM debian:jessie

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y cron curl apt-utils nano curl apache2 apache2-utils libmysqlclient-dev
RUN apt-get -y install python3 libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3 gettext
RUN ln /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python
RUN apt-get -y install python3-pip
RUN ln /usr/bin/pip3 /usr/bin/pip
RUN pip install --upgrade pip

ADD ./webapp_2.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default_000.conf
RUN mkdir /webapp
WORKDIR /webapp
ADD ./requirements.txt /webapp/ 
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ADD . /webapp/

ADD ./crontab /var/spool/cron/crontabs/root
RUN chmod 0600 /var/spool/cron/crontabs/root

CMD touch /var/log/cron.log && cron && env > /root/env.sh && tail -f /var/log/cron.log

CMD ["/usr/sbin/crond", "-f", "-d", "0"]
CMD ["/usr/sbin/apache2", "-D",  "FOREGROUND"]
```

Pero hasta el mento no logo ejecutar el proceso, ¿alguien podrá ayudarme por favor o indicarme que me falta?

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

`CMD` sólo puede usarse una vez (sólo el último tiene efecto). No sirve para ejecutar comandos, sino para *especificar qué comando* se ejecutará cuando instancies el contenedor sin pasarle como argumento qué comando ejecutar.

En tu caso, si creas la imagen dándole como nombre por ejemplo `miprueba`:

```
$ docker build -t miprueba .
```

Y luego la instancias sin especificar comando:

```
$ docker run miprueba
```

se ejecutará el comando especificado en el último `CMD` del dockerfile, ignorándose los anteriores.

La solución cuando quieres ejecutar varios comandos es escribirlos todos en un shell scrip y usar como `CMD` del Dockerfile uno que lance un shell (ej, bash) pasándole como parámetro ese script. Otra opción es usar para `CMD` la sintaxis "shell", y así usar operadores como `&&` para lanzar varios en una línea.

Comment: Pero cuando corro docker run miprueba /bin/bash, para visualizar mi log y corroborar que funcione, no me corre el crontab. Sabrás a que se debe ?

Comment: Cuando lanzas docker con un comando (`docker run imagen comando`) el comando en cuestión sustituye al especificado en `CMD`. Lo que puedes hacer es lanzarlo sin comando (`docker run imagen`) y luego "entrar" en el contenedor en ejecución mediante `docker exec -it contenedor bash`. Eso te permite ejecutar _otro_ comando sobre un contenedor que ya estaba arrancado. Cuando salgas con `exit` no se detendrá el contenedor original, sino sólo terminará la ejecución de ese `bash`